# Replacing contents of a text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've looked all around this site and can't quite seem to find anything that fits my situation. Basically, I am trying to write an addition to the NETLOGON file that will replace text in a text file on all of our users' desktops. The current text is static across the board.

The text I want it changed to will be unique to each user. I want to change the current text (user1) to the users AD username (i.e. johnd, janed, etc.). I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and all the workstations are Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 bit.

Here's what I have tried so far (with a few variables, which none have worked for one reason or the other):

```
gc c:\Users\%USERNAME%\desktop\VPN.txt' -replace "user1",$env:username | out-file c:\Users\%USERNAME%\desktop\VPN.txt
```

I didn't get an error, but it also did not go back to the normal "PS C:>" prompt, just ">>>" and the file did not change as anticipated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If that is how you have the code exactly then I suppose it is because you have an opening single quote without a closing one. You are still going to have two other problems and you have one answer in your code. The `>>>` is the line continuation characters because the parser knows that the code is not complete and giving you the option to continue with the code. If you were purposely coding a single line on multiple lines you would consider this a feature.

```psh
$path = "c:\Users\$($env:username)\desktop\VPN.txt" 
(Get-Content $path) -replace "user1",$env:username | out-file $path
```

- Closed the path in quotes and used a variable since you called the path twice.
- `%name%` is used in command prompt. Environment variables in PowerShell use the `$env:` provider which you did you once in your snippet.
- `-replace` is a regex replaced tool that can work against `Get-Content` but you need to capture the result in a sub expression first.
- Secondly with  `-replace` is for regex and your string is not regex based you could just use `.Replace()` as well.
- `Set-Content` is generally preferred over `Out-File` for performance reasons.

**All that being said...**

you could also try something like this.

```psh
$path = "c:\Users\$($env:username)\desktop\VPN.txt"
(Get-Content $path).Replace("user1",$env:username) | Set-Content $path
```

**Do you want to only replace the first occurrence?**

You could use a little regex here with a tweak in how you get the use `Get-Content`

```
$path = "c:\Users\$($env:username)\desktop\VPN.txt" 
(Get-Content $path | Out-String) -replace "(.*?)user1(.*)",('$1{0}$2' -f $env:username) | out-file $path
```

Regex will match the entire file. There are two groups which it captures.

1. `(.*?)` - Up until the first "user1"
2. `(.*)` - Everything after that

Then we use the format operator to sandwich the new username in between those capture groups.

Comment: The first on worked great Thank You! On a side note, I didn't realize there was another field that contained user 1 that I didn't want changed on the next line. Is there a way to only have it replace that line and change the other one to something different? (i.e. change user1 to $env:username and change passuser1 to pass1234).

Comment: @TimothyWhite Made a small update if it helps. As for changing the password that would be dependent on where it is located in the file and would most likely be another question. If you knew what the password was ahead of time you could chain the `-replace "user","user2" -replace "werwq","asdf"` Obligatory flaming when I know you are storing passwords in clear text files.

Comment: Excellent answer Matt. Thanks for taking the time to cover it so thoroughly, it was really helpful.

Comment: Life saver... one simple line

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
(Get-Content $fileName) | % {
    if ($_.ReadCount -eq 1) {
        $_ -replace "$original", "$content"
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $fileName
```