# Move all files with a certain extension from multiple subdirectories into same subdirectory structure using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I am trying to read multiple CSV files inside multiple sub directories and doing some row deletion based on filter using PowerShell scripting.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path J:\new -Recurse -Filter daq*.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Where {
        $_ -notmatch "serverTime"
    } | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

But I want the output to be in same directory structure as the source file.
The directory structure is as below:

```
root/
   sub_dir1/
       1.csv
       2.csv
   sub_dir2/
       1.csv
       2.csv
```

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Explain what is happening / not happening with your script. Does it do anything? Are all files created in a single folder?

Comment: Currently its creating the files in the same directory, but the issue is its overwriting the original file with empty file as I am passing `$_.FullName` , because i want to retain the original file name.
I tried searching on the internet if there is a way to edit the original file itself and not to produce an out-file but didn't found anything

Comment: So you DO want to replace the original file?

Comment: Yes, if replacing the original file works out, it will do for me

Comment: `Get-Content $_.FullName | ...` -> `(Get-Content $_.FullName) | ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not optimal, or even idiomatic, but the following worked in a quick test:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path J:\new -Recurse -Filter daq*.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $origFile = $_
        $filteredContent = Get-Content $origFile.FullName | Where{$_ -notmatch "serverTime"} 
        $filteredContent | Out-File $origFile.FullName
    }
```

All we're doing, is loading the content of each file and filtering it to `$filteredContent`, then writing it back out to the original file.

Another option (courtesy of [Replacing Contents of a Text File Using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010480/replacing-contents-of-a-text-file-using-powershell)) is to wrap the `Get-Content` command in parens, which forces the full content to be loaded and then passed down the pipeline. This will give shorter code, but arguably it's less understandable e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path J:\new -Recurse -Filter daq*.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $origFile = $_
        ( Get-Content $origFile.FullName ) | 
            Where{$_ -notmatch "serverTime"} | 
            Out-File $origFile.FullName
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @andyb , its working, but my file size is increasing to almost double

Comment: My guess would be that original files are an 8-bit format (ascii) and PowerShell is re-writing them in a 16-bit format (unicode). You can force a particular format by adding an `-Encoding` parameter to `Out-File`.

Comment: Yes , you are correct., Powershell was re-writing those in unicode. changed it to -encoding ascii

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, you can mark it as correct, or, if you prefer, wait a while to see if someone else has a better, solution.

Comment: I have marked it as a Answer